# The expected [App\Events\Frontend\Auth\UserLoggedIn] event was not dispatched. Failed asserting that false is true

Tags: php, laravel, testing, laravel-dusk

I am trying to test my website with dusk, but in many tests i wrote, it is getting failed.
I've used laravel boilerplate 6.0 and dusk for testing.

Below are the code and few test cases and error/failure details.

Login.blade.php

```
@extends('frontend.layouts.app')

@section('title', app_name() . ' | ' . __('labels.frontend.auth.login_box_title'))

@section('content')
    <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="col col-sm-8 align-self-center">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <strong>
                        @lang('labels.frontend.auth.login_box_title')
                    </strong>
                </div><!--card-header-->

                <div class="card-body">
                    {{ html()->form('POST', route('frontend.auth.login.post'))->open() }}
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {{ html()->label(__('validation.attributes.frontend.email'))->for('email') }}

                                    {{ html()->email('email')
                                        ->class('form-control')
                                        ->placeholder(__('validation.attributes.frontend.email'))
                                        ->attribute('maxlength', 191)
                                        ->required() }}
                                </div><!--form-group-->
                            </div><!--col-->
                        </div><!--row-->

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {{ html()->label(__('validation.attributes.frontend.password'))->for('password') }}

                                    {{ html()->password('password')
                                        ->class('form-control')
                                        ->placeholder(__('validation.attributes.frontend.password'))
                                        ->required() }}
                                </div><!--form-group-->
                            </div><!--col-->
                        </div><!--row-->

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        {{ html()->label(html()->checkbox('remember', true, 1) . ' ' . __('labels.frontend.auth.remember_me'))->for('remember') }}
                                    </div>
                                </div><!--form-group-->
                            </div><!--col-->
                        </div><!--row-->

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="form-group clearfix">
                                    {{ form_submit(__('labels.frontend.auth.login_button')) }}
                                </div><!--form-group-->
                            </div><!--col-->
                        </div><!--row-->

                        @if(config('access.captcha.login'))
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    @captcha
                                    {{ html()->hidden('captcha_status', 'true') }}
                                </div><!--col-->
                            </div><!--row-->
                        @endif

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="form-group text-right">
                                    <a href="{{ route('frontend.auth.password.reset') }}">@lang('labels.frontend.passwords.forgot_password')</a>
                                </div><!--form-group-->
                            </div><!--col-->
                        </div><!--row-->
                    {{ html()->form()->close() }}

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="text-center">
                                @include('frontend.auth.includes.socialite')
                            </div>
                        </div><!--col-->
                    </div><!--row-->
                </div><!--card body-->
            </div><!--card-->
        </div><!-- col-md-8 -->
    </div><!-- row -->
@endsection

@push('after-scripts')
    @if(config('access.captcha.login'))
        @captchaScripts
    @endif
@endpush
```

UserLoginTest.php

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Browser;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;

use App\Events\Frontend\Auth\UserLoggedIn;
use App\Events\Frontend\Auth\UserLoggedOut;
use App\Models\Auth\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;
use Tests\DuskTestCase;
// use Tests\TestCase;

class UserLoginTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    /**
     * A Dusk test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    use RefreshDatabase;

    /** @test */
    public function the_login_route_exists()
    {
        $this->get('/login')->assertStatus(200);
    }

    /** @test */
    public function a_user_can_login_with_email_and_password()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create([
            'email' => 'john@example.com',
            'password' => 'secret',
        ]);
        Event::fake();

        $this->post('/login', [
            'email' => 'john@example.com',
            'password' => 'secret',
        ]);

        Event::assertDispatched(UserLoggedIn::class);
        $this->assertAuthenticatedAs($user);
    }
```

Error:
There was 1 failure:

1. Tests\Browser\UserLoginTest::a_user_can_login_with_email_and_password
   The expected [App\Events\Frontend\Auth\UserLoggedIn] event was not dispatched.
   Failed asserting that false is true.

/home/hrishi/TheNewBegining/PHP/Laravel/WebApp-X/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Testing/Fakes/EventFake.php:62
/home/hrishi/TheNewBegining/PHP/Laravel/WebApp-X/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:261
/home/hrishi/TheNewBegining/PHP/Laravel/WebApp-X/tests/Browser/UserLoginTest.php:46

I've just started coding, and have little experience.
Help me out.

Comment: You can't do dusk tests the same way you do http tests. The event does not get dispatched in the same lifecycle as the test. The event might be dispatched but the TestCase event fake will not be the one receiving the event. You need a way to determine if the user logged in successfully that can be determined from the browser page (maybe you have a success message or the user's name somewhere in the page) because that is all the information dusk has to work with